# Modulo não encontra atributo do def

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Tenho que achar na questão, o email e o wpp pelo nome que for inserido, e preciso por isso em um def na task.py por exemplo, que fiz assim:

```
import __init__

def encontrar(elemento):
    pos_i = __init__.wpp
    pos_j = __init__.email

for i in range(len(__init__.agenda)):
    for j in __init__.agenda[i]:
        if elemento in __init__.agenda[i][j]:
            pos_i = i
            pos_j = j
            break
        break
return (pos_i, pos_j)
```

minha init esta assim:

```
import task

agenda = []
contatos = []

nome = input('Digite o nome: ')
wpp = int(input('Digite o número: '))
email = input('Email: ')
contatos = [nome, wpp, email]
agenda.append(contatos)

r = task.encontrar('ana')
print(r)
```

Mas da o seguinte erro:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Estrutura de Dados/LIST - Lista de Exercícios/E1/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
   import task
  File "Estrutura de Dados\LIST - Lista de Exercícios\E1\task.py", line 1, in 
<module>
   import __init__
     File "Estrutura de Dados\LIST - Lista de Exercícios\E1\__init__.py", 
line 12, 
   in <module>
   r = task.encontrar('ana')
   AttributeError: module 'task' has no attribute 'encontrar'
```

Comment: O arquivo __init__.py convencionalmente será executado quando seu módulo for importado, no mais, pelo seu traceback, eu diria para substituir esse `import task` por `from E1 import task`, se você está dentro da pasta `LIST - Lista de Exercícios`, e então executar o seu arquivo. Outra coisa, seu arquivo task.py está com os níveis de identação do método errados a partir do laço for.

Comment: Dentro da pasta  `LIST - Lista de Exercícios` tem a task 'E1' do pycharm com os arquivos, tentei por esse outro import mas não funciona, unresolved reference E1 e task

Comment: Uma duvida, em qual pasta você está com seu terminal aberto enquanto chama o interpretador python? A pasta onde você o chama será considerado a raiz do seu projeto e isso afetará seus imports. O pycharm é só uma IDE, seria interessante você executar de fora dele para entender melhor como está organizado o seu projeto.

Comment: Foi mal, mas não entendi sua pergunta, sempre fiz tudo nessa pasta, inclusive tem outros exemplos que chamam o modulo em outra init e funciona sem problemas